# Get list of shipping methods for a subsidiary

Tags: ruby, netsuite, suitetalk

I'm using NetSweet/NetSuite Ruby gem for connecting to NetSuite accounts.

Normally it's trivial to get list of shipping methods using `get_select_value`. However one NetSuite account is organized into subsidiaries, and shipping methods are assigned to subsidiaries. For this particular account, `get_select_value` returns empty list:

```
NetSuite::Records::BaseRefList.get_select_value({
    recordType: "salesOrder",
    field: "shipMethod",
}).base_refs.length
=> 0
```

This makes some sense: in new sales order form the list of shipping methods is initially empty. When I select "customer" option, NetSuite automatically fills the read-only field "subsidiary". Then list of available shipping methods is populated.

Is there a way to fetch list of shipping methods by subsidiary or for a customer?

NetSuite API response contains a warning: "Results are incomplete. You must provide a value for field entity."

Full response:

```
    <getSelectValueResponse xmlns="urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
      <platformCore:getSelectValueResult xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformCore:status isSuccess="true">
          <platformCore:statusDetail type="WARN">
            <platformCore:code>WARNING</platformCore:code>
            <platformCore:message>Results are incomplete. You must provide a value for field entity.</platformCore:message>
          </platformCore:statusDetail>
        </platformCore:status>
        <platformCore:totalRecords>0</platformCore:totalRecords>
        <platformCore:totalPages>0</platformCore:totalPages>
      </platformCore:getSelectValueResult>
    </getSelectValueResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using filterByValueList and passing customer internalId as entity seems to work.

```
NetSuite::Records::BaseRefList.get_select_value({
    recordType: "salesOrder",
    field: "shipMethod",
    filterByValueList: {
      "platformCore:filterBy" => {
        "platformCore:field" => "entity",
      "platformCore:internalId" => ns_customer.internal_id}
    }
}).base_refs.length
=> 17
```

It's somewhat counter-intuitive, as filter option should reduce items in the output.

Generated XML:

```
    <platformMsgs:getSelectValue>
      <platformMsgs:pageIndex>1</platformMsgs:pageIndex>
      <platformMsgs:fieldDescription>
        <platformCore:recordType>salesOrder</platformCore:recordType>
        <platformCore:field>shipMethod</platformCore:field>
        <platformCore:filterByValueList>
          <platformCore:filterBy>
            <platformCore:field>entity</platformCore:field>
            <platformCore:internalId>4978501</platformCore:internalId>
          </platformCore:filterBy>
        </platformCore:filterByValueList>
      </platformMsgs:fieldDescription>
    </platformMsgs:getSelectValue>
```